# Closing Blender as soon as "export finished" gets printed by script executed with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, scripting, export

In the following code, Blender2.79 is opened with a project and two Python scripts are executed in succession from command line. The last Python script outputs the string `"export finished in xx.xxxx sec."` after completion. How do I catch this output and end the subprocess (Blender) accordingly? This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
# blender project.blend --python main.py --python fbxexport.py
cmd = ["D:\\Blender279\\blender.exe",
       "D:\\...\\project.blend",
       "--python",
       "D:\\...\\Scripts\\Main.py",
       "--python",
       "D:\\...\\Python_FBX_Export\\fbxexportanim.py"]
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
sStdout, sStdErr = p1.communicate()
# i want to do something like...
# if "export finished" in str(sStdout): # if fbxexportanim is finished
#    p1.kill()
# ... but p1.communicate() waits until end-of-file is reached, that's why this does not work
```

This is the `fbxexportanim.py` script:

```
import bpy

# for anim
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="D:\\...\\fbx\\anim.fbx", 
use_selection=True,
apply_unit_scale=0.01,
object_types={'OTHER', 'MESH', 'ARMATURE'},
mesh_smooth_type='FACE', add_leaf_bones=False, use_armature_deform_only=True,
bake_anim_use_nla_strips=False, bake_anim_use_all_actions=False)
```

### Note

I've posted this question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177030/closing-blender-as-soon-as-export-finished-gets-printed-by-script-executed-wit) already, but it got no attention. That's why I decided to post it here as well. I hope this is not against the rules.

Comment: Try pexpect! It allows the opening of system sub processes, and then waits for certain responses if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunately pexpect.spawn() only works under Linux :/

Comment: Huh? But... I have pexpect on Windows... maybe only the run() part works, though.

Comment: How? The documentation states that pexpect.spawn() and pexpect.run() do not work under windows, see https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows

There are replacement functions like pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn, pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn but they do not behave in the same way unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe when I installed it it still worked. I forgot to install it on this latest version of python, though.

Comment: It seems like `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn()` does actually work for me, but I'm not sure exactly - will test it in the next hours. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work because `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn()` does not use a virtual terminal and that's why Blender does not output fbx export debugging information

Comment: I’m surprised blender does not close on its own... use -b to disable the interface.

Comment: I've tried that already, but the script which loads a mesh does not work correctly if -b is used, I don't know why :(